# TYPO3 - Automatically Sending E-Mail/Newsletter depending on given value in database

Tags: php, mysql, email, typo3, typo3-7.6.x

I have a fairly large table with unique records including date (renewal date) information and I want to send an email (once a week/month) with values from this table to the email address (or to multiple addresses given in a string separated by `,`) in that table (or from another table in case of leftJOIN or MJOIN) when the value of the 'renewal date' reaches e.g. 30 days prior to current date.

The table is not located in the same database as the TYPO3 instance. I also would like to style the email.

What's the best way to do so and how can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 0):

you can programm a Scheduler Task. 
In this Scheduler Task you query the external DB, for an example look at the Extension "svconnector_sql", it's an addtional extension for "external_import".
The underlying concept is to use the core Extension "ADODB" to make a connection to an external DB and make the queries. More details in this Extensions.
After that you can build an E-Mail HTML Template, or better download a ready template, for Example by [Litmus](https://litmus.com/resources/free-responsive-email-templates).

This Template use in Combination with TYPO3 Fluid, to integrate you results from DB query. here is an Example, for using Fluid and send this as Email. [wiki.typo3.org](https://wiki.typo3.org/How_to_use_the_Fluid_Standalone_view_to_render_template_based_emails)